# How mutliple queries are executed at driver end?

Tags: oracle, drivers

When we send multiple queries to oracle at a time, how it is handling.
It may handle by using any algorithm, or it may start threads to handle multiple queries.

Can you please help us to understand the concept behind oracle query execution?

Answer (score 0):

As with any decent RDBMS, Oracle uses multiple server-side threads to process queries in  parallel.

The JDBC drivers are designed to be used from multiple threads, but are unlikely to create their own (client-side) threads except (possibly) for implementing timeouts.  If there is significant parallelism on the client side, it is likely to be the doing of the application itself.